# python asyncore client example

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to implement as asynchronous TCP Client - Server model in python. It's my first example of using asyncore module and i need some explanation if anyone can provide me.

I have the following requirements :
[Client]

1. Initiate a client instance - connect to server if server is running else wait for the server to come up.
2. I need to receive / transmit data from server.
3. Notify me whenever data is received on the socket.

I tried running a sample example from net but had some doubts :

```
import asyncore
import logging
import socket
from cStringIO import StringIO
import urlparse

class Client(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self,host):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.write_buffer = ""
        self.read_buffer = StringIO()
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        address = (host, 80)
        self.logger.debug('connecting to %s', address)
        self.connect(address)

    def handle_connect(self):
        self.logger.debug('handle_connect()')

    def handle_close(self):
        self.logger.debug('handle_close()')
        self.close()

    def writable(self):
        is_writable = (len(self.write_buffer) > 0)
        if is_writable:
            self.logger.debug('writable() -> %s', is_writable)
        return is_writable

    def readable(self):
        self.logger.debug('readable() -> True')
        return True

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.write_buffer)
        self.logger.debug('handle_write() -> "%s"', self.write_buffer[:sent])
        self.write_buffer = self.write_buffer[sent:]

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        self.logger.debug('handle_read() -> %d bytes', len(data))
        self.read_buffer.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(name)s: %(message)s',
                        )

    clients = Client("127.0.0.1")

    logging.debug('LOOP STARTING')

    asyncore.loop()

    logging.debug('LOOP DONE')
```

1. How does dispatcher class notifies when data is available to read
   from socket. Is handle_read called in that scenario ?
2. Is it a busy polling mechanism ? will it eat my whole cpu even if socket is
   sitting idle ?
3. Above example does not wait for server to come up. How can do this ?
4. how can write data to socket from client ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but maybe may be useful to someone:

http://effbot.org/librarybook/asyncore.htm